# What is the meaning of `DOPE`?

Tags: meaning, slang

What is the meaning of `DOPE`?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I recently joined a Google+ Group, the reply of a user is

> So DOPE!!!

I do not understand it, I can only guess it is good or nice, or another similar meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dope](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dope) has, as you can see, many meanings. In your case it is an adjective, and is used in an informal way of saying that something is very good.

Comment: Why it use capital. not `dope`

Comment: It is probably capitalized to emphasize that is was _really_ good. It doesn't have any special meaning.

Comment: FWIW, **dope** in this sense is from the slang vocabulary of a recent teen generation.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  Not all that recent.  It's been common slang [for at least 25 years](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/06/24/dope-etymology-history/).

Comment: It didn't really hit its stride nationally, though, until maybe 10 years ago.